# I cannot consume my publications in Meteor template's helper

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I defined the following publication on the server side:

```
  Meteor.publish('observedQuestionsFeed',function(){
        _self = this;
        return Questions.find({
            observedByUsers : {$exists: true,$elemMatch: {$eq:_self.userId}}});
    });
```

which returns what I need;

then i defined a subscription to that publication in my template as follows:

```
Template.observedQuestions.onCreated(function(){
    var self = this;
    self.autorun(function(){
        self.subscribe('observedQuestionsFeed');
    });
});
```

but I cannot consume that publication in my helper as I would need to repeat same query as I understand but $eq is not recognised;

I put :

```
Template.observedQuestions.helpers({
    observedQuestions : function(){
        questions =  Questions.find({
            observedByUsers : {$exists: true,$elemMatch: {$eq:Meteor.userId()}}});
        return questions;
    }
});
```

which does not work due to $eq not recognised.
I want to use this very specific publication only in this particular template.How should I do it? (observedByUsers field is a simple array of usersIds or is undefined in my mongo collection)

Answer (score 0):

In your publish function, you're already filtering the records down to what you want.  If that is five records for example, you're only sending those five records to the client.  Because of that you should just be able to do:

```
Template.observedQuestions.helpers({
    observedQuestions : function(){
        return Questions.find();
    }
});
```

Comment: That is what I thought but it returns the whole collection not only the docs I selected on the server side;maybe it has to do with my other templates on the page which also use the same collection..